# "Not defined" javascript error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm very new to JS, and understand that my script is probably terrible, but it all works fine in Safari and Chrome, just not in Firefox.

Amongst other things, I'm calling two functions to hide and reveal a custom Quicktime movie controller by placing a "mask" over the top of it (I know a toggle would be a more elegant solution, but I couldn't get such a function to work the way I wanted). Anyway, this is what the Javascript looks like:

```
function revealControls(){
      document.getElementById("controlsCover");
      controlsCover.style.display ="none"
}

function hideControls(){
       document.getElementById("controlsCover");
       controlsCover.style.display ="block"
}
```

I'm calling these functions with different mouse events applied to various divs, such as:

```
<div id = "controls" onmouseout = "hideControls()">
```

Firefox is telling me

```
 "Error: controlsCover is not defined",
```

and I have no idea how to define the element as null.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it's something very simple — but I have virtually no experience with Javascript. Yet.

Comment: how the heck would this work under safari or chrome.....

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/noob-javascript-resources http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/learn-javascript-videos http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info all great places to start learning and picking up resources . STAY AWAY FROM W3SCHOOLS!!!!! MDN is your new friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create the `controlsCover` variable first to reference it.

When you first use `document.getElementById("controlsCover")`, this will return a HTML element of which you pass to a variable to use.

If you uncomment the console.log - you'll see what is inside the variable.

```
function revealControls()       
{
    var controlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");
    /* console.log(controlsCover) */
    controlsCover.style.display ="none"
}

function hideControls() 
{
    var controlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");
    controlsCover.style.display ="block"
}
```

Comment: So, Chrome and Safari are clever enough to check whether a variable exists as HTML-Element before throwing an `undefined` error?

Comment: got there faster than me! @Amberlamps without seeing your full code its hard to say why it works in the other browsers,

Comment: Thank you so much, @Glycerine! Very grateful for the quick response. I've created variables properly inside all my functions now, and everything is working in Firefox. I remember a similar structure from when I did a little flash coding years ago... makes so much sense now. @Amberlamps, I guess you're right about the other browsers filling in the blanks.

Comment: @NickSimpson-Deeks: Accept a question as correct, if it solves your problem please.

Comment: @NickSimpson-Deeks No problem dude. You'll find a lot of similarities between actionscript and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign `document.getElementById` return value to `controlsCover` variable:

```
var controlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");
```

Fixed will be:

```
function revealControls() {
    var controlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");
    controlsCover.style.display ="none"
}

function hideControls() {
    var controlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");
    controlsCover.style.display ="block"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ele =document.getElementById("controlsCover");
ele.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function revealControls()       
{
  var oControlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");

  if (oControlsCover) {
    oControlsCover.style.display ="none";
  }
}

function hideControls() 
{
  var oControlsCover = document.getElementById("controlsCover");

  if (oControlsCover) {
    oControlsCover.style.display ="block";
  }
}
```